# Is it permissible to say a portion of the Serenity prayer

Tags: halal-haram, salat, dua, phrase

I came across the following prayer titled the [Serenity Prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serenity_Prayer):

```
        God grant me the serenity
        to accept the things I cannot change; 
        courage to change the things I can; 
        and wisdom to know the difference.
```

I originally found it in a Campus Bible Talks book to change negative thinking processes; it was written by Reinhold Niebuhr and I believe the original is longer.

As a Muslim is it permissible to use this as a prayer when making a prayer to Allah Kareem, providing 'God' is replaced with 'Allah', I wasn't sure if it was permissible as the original prayer was written by a non-muslim.

Comment: Basically I can't see any reason why it shouldn't be permissible as AFAIK there seems to be no objection to the teachings of Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Religiously adopting a fixed ritual which is not prescribed in Islam is bidah, even if it was invented by a Muslim. Further, imitating non muslims is haram.

You should say duas that have an origin in Islam, such as from Quran and Hadith, we have much more beautiful duas than this.

Answer (score 0):

I find it similar to making a dua on your own. Seems like it would be fine to me as you can make a dua in any language and ask for anything within the limits of islam.

Answer (score 0):

One must keep in mind that there are numerous dua that are found within the Quran itself and the authentic hadeeth which can be used when supplicating to Allah, and these are the most preferred. But one can also use their own language and words when supplicating, as long as those words uttered do not contradict the Quran and Sunnah.

Here are  40 Duas from The Holy Quran That Start With “Rabbana” http://quranreading.com/blog/40-rabbana-duas/

Answer (score -2):

There is no ritual here being added, it is a prayer, one can NOT omit a prayer simply because it's being used by xyz to call upon the same Al-Mighty.

Nor is there any imitation here, simply trying to figure out if a prayer you like can be used, in the end your intentions are what matters and they seem pretty clean and pure, you aren't invoking anyone other than your Creator, what you mean by saying "God" or anything else is clear to you and your Creator.

And the Quran speaks of prayers asked by many prophets prior, Moses, Jesus, Abraham including their wives (not Jesus (explicitly stating before someone jumps down my throat)).